# M.Excel Formula for Prioritization

Tags: microsoft-excel

please help if any of you know what formula to use to sort the items below

- Layer 1: If there is a "Greater" or "Unsatisfactory" in any of the cell range, I will get 1.5
- Layer 2: If Layer 1 is not met , if there is a "Effective" in any of the cell 
  range, I will get 4.5
- Layer 3: If Layer 1 & 2 above do not met, I will get 7.5

The prioritization is from Layer 1 ->Layer 2 -> Layer. The thing is, I need all 3 layers/formula in one cell.

Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use COUNTIF on the range to see if they exist, if so put the value desired.

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(A1:D1,{"Greater","Unsatisfactory"})),1.5,IF(COUNTIF(A1:D1,"Effective"),4.5,7.5))
```

Where A1:D1 is the range to be tested.

Comment: how about on the above formula, I would like to add in an additional rule if A1:D1 all cells are "Effective, the result will show 1.5 as well?

Comment: Layer 2 states otherwise.

Comment: @Dave My guess is that the person who did so either does not understand that the condition in the IF does not need to resolve to TRUE/FALSE, that 0 = FALSE and anything greater than 0 is TRUE.  Or, felt that this did not deserve an answer, but the latter would indicate that they would have down voted the question also, so we are back to misunderstanding the formula.